# Is it possible to embed a Google Form into a Gmail signature?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-forms

I'm trying to figure out how or if it's possible to embed a Google Form (a customer satisfaction survey) into my employees email signatures so that it's automatically there when they compose an email. They are not computer savvy at all so the simpler the better.

The Google Form gives the option to embed the link in an iframe but in the actual emails it just shows up as the embed code and not the form itself. I think this was asked before but the thread I found was several years ago so I wasn't sure if there was any kind of workaround/solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, this is not possible due to security reasons. You can't have people embedding websites or external applications into their signatures, or Gmail would be the world's premier virus breeding grounds.
You can embed images and hyperlinks **if you have enabled Rich Text Format** into the signature but that's about it.

Answer (score 2):

> **Yes its Possible.**

i know this is an old post but this answer is for anyone else looking for the same solution to a similar problem quite recently.

Heres is the simple solution -

First we need to generate an (gmail) email tamplate - this template will contain your signature & the full google form embeded which the customers can submit from that email itself - how you get their attention to fill up the form will be upto your imiganiation.

This template can then be used when emailing any of your customers.

Here are the steps to generate the template (All screenshots attached):

1) Go to the Form that you want your customers to fill up - click on Edit form.

2) Click on Send  - enter your own email address.

3) Tick Mark "Embed Form in Email"

[image: Steps 1,2 & 3]

4) Open the Email You have Just Received -you will see it contains the form embeded.

5) Click on Reply

[image: Steps 4 & 5]

6) Delete the subject or Set as per your requirment.

7) Edit your Signature just above the Embeded Form.

[image: Steps 6 & 7]

8) Once done - click on the 3 tiny dots on the right hand side of the new Email next to the Trash Icon

9) Click on "Templates" - Next Click "Save Draft As Template " Next Click on "Save as New Template" - Set a template name as per your choice.

[image: Steps 8 & 9]
[image: Step 9]

10) Thast it! The Master Email Template with the Google Form Embeded Signature has been created- Close the New Email Message.

11) To use the template in any new Email - follow step 9 & Click on your Template as per the name you gave it.

[image: Step 11]

This is a one time headache but it gets the job done, if you want to deploy this across multiple users - follow all the steps above & in Step 2 add the users email address instead of your own, help them set it up on their accounts with the very same steps above.

Its quite obvious that you will need to teach the users how to use templates when sending new email meaages to make their lives easier especially if they are not tech savy.